# Testing Express routes with Sinon stubs

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to unit test Express routes to verify they call the correct controller functions. At this point, I'm not checking the internal logic of the controller functions, only that the routes map to the right functions. What I have so far works perfectly until I introduce router middleware like so:

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import config from './../../config/environments';
import SuperLogin from 'superlogin';

let controller = require('./subjects.controller');
let router = express.Router();
let superlogin = new SuperLogin(config);

router.get('/', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin', 'specialist', 'nurse']), controller.index);
router.get('/:subjectId', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin', 'specialist', 'nurse']), controller.show);
router.post('/', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin', 'specialist', 'nurse']), controller.create);
router.put('/:subjectId', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin', 'specialist', 'nurse']), controller.upsert);
router.patch('/:subjectId', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin', 'specialist', 'nurse']), controller.patch);
router.delete('/:subjectId', superlogin.requireAuth, superlogin.requireAnyRole(['admin']), controller.destroy);


module.exports = router;
```

As you can see I'm using [Superlogin](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin) to verify access to each route. If I remove this my tests pass, adding the middleware causes them to fail. I probably need to stub the superlogin methods but I don't know where to do this.

My test is as follows

```
'use strict';

/* globals sinon, describe, expect, it */

let proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache();

let subjectCtrlStub = {
    index: 'subjectCtrl.index',
    show: 'subjectCtrl.show',
    create: 'subjectCtrl.create',
    upsert: 'subjectCtrl.upsert',
    patch: 'subjectCtrl.patch',
    destroy: 'subjectCtrl.destroy'
};

sinon.stub(superlogin, 'requireAuth', function(req, res, next) {
    return next();
});

let routerStub = {
    get: sinon.spy(),
    put: sinon.spy(),
    patch: sinon.spy(),
    post: sinon.spy(),
    delete: sinon.spy()
};

// require the index with our stubbed out modules
let subjectRoutes = proxyquire('./subjects.routes.js', {
    express: {
        Router() {
            return routerStub;
        }
    },
    './subjects.controller': subjectCtrlStub
});

describe('Subject API Router:', function() {

    it('should return an express router instance', function() {
        subjectRoutes.should.equal(routerStub);
    });

    describe('GET /api/subjects', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.index', function() {
            routerStub.get
                .withArgs('/', 'subjectCtrl.index')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });

    describe('GET /api/subjects/:subjectId', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.show', function() {
            routerStub.get
                .withArgs('/:subjectId', 'subjectCtrl.show')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });

    describe('POST /api/subjects', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.create', function() {
            routerStub.post
                .withArgs('/', 'subjectCtrl.create')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });

    describe('PUT /api/subjects/:subjectId', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.upsert', function() {
            routerStub.put
                .withArgs('/:subjectId', 'subjectCtrl.upsert')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });

    describe('PATCH /api/subjects/:subjectId', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.patch', function() {
            routerStub.patch
                .withArgs('/:subjectId', 'subjectCtrl.patch')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });

    describe('DELETE /api/subjects/:subjectId', function() {
        it('should route to subjects.controller.destroy', function() {
            routerStub.delete
                .withArgs('/:subjectId', 'subjectCtrl.destroy')
                .should.have.been.calledOnce;
        });
    });
});
```

I have a before function that runs ahead of all of these tests that seeds the database with some example users with different roles and saves Authorization tokens to a global variable for use when testing the endpoints, I just don't know how to send them with the routerStub function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use [stubs](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Stub.html) to provide a direct or inderect **inputs** of the SUT with known values.

You probably think about the verfification of a fact, what a view function should be reachable from the routing in some conditions. In this case use stubs to provide middlewares with input data that affect their behavior (such as user credentials what is used for an authentication for example). Don't substitute  middlewares itself with stubs because such test would be irrelevant if stub totally changes the behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how I can pass in credentials when using the routerStub.get method? Superlogin uses token-based auth to decide on access control, but as I'm not testing using a HTTP request I can't add Authorization headers.

Comment: It would be a great idea to use a fake HTTP requests for a routing testing. So tests could cover a different real-world scenarios for a different kinds of users (anonymous, authenticated with various roles)). Why do not try a `supertest-as-promised` for example?